# Login to a website using beego

Tags: mysql, authentication, orm, beego

I think i have a problem with my syntax but i can't find it. I tried to login but it always ended up with 404 pages.

[image: i]

this is routers/router.go :

```
beego.Router("/", &controllers.AccController{},"get:Home")
beego.Router("/acc/login", &controllers.AccController{}, "get,post:Post")
beego.Router("/acc/signup", &controllers.AccController{}, "get,post:Add")
beego.Router("/acc/home", &controllers.AccController{}, "get:Home")
```

and controllers/acc.go :

```
func (acc *AccController) Post() {
username := acc.Input().Get("Username")
password := acc.Input().Get("Password")
if username=="" || password=="" {
    acc.Data["err"] = "Please fill the form and then click submit!"
    acc.TplName = "acc/login.tpl"
} else {
    u := &models.Users{Username:username}
    ok,user := u.Login(username,password)
    if ok {
        acc.SetSession("webpro", user)
            //Find the contents of the corresponding permissions here
            acc.Ctx.Redirect(302, "/acc/home")
    } else {
        acc.Data["err"] = "Wrong username or password!"
        acc.TplName = "acc/login.tpl"
    }
}
```

Here is views/acc/login.tpl :

```
<body class="login-img3-body">

    <div class="container">

      <form class="login-form" action="/login" method="POST">        
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="{{.Users.Username}}" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="{{.Users.Password}}">
            </div>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a></span>
            </label>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Signup</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

I'm a newbee so, please correct me if i wrong.

Comment: I don't know a syntax of go language, but I see that your paths are different. In routes you've provided `/acc/login` but in form you're sending request to `/login`. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, i'm still confused why

Comment: What is left to be confused about? Can't you simply change your route to `beego.Router("/login", &controllers.AccController{}, "get,post:Post")`?

Comment: it didn't works

Answer (score 0):

1.Change web access pass to localhost:8080/acc/login

2.Change `acc.Ctx.Redirect(302, "/acc/home")`
to `acc.Redirect("/acc/home", 301)`

Worked for me!